# why permission denied for superuser in drf?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here I set permission like this for normal users in my views but the permission applied for the superuser also(which i don't want).

my superuser doesn't belongs to this query `return qs.filter...exists()` so I get permission denied.

But I didn't get that why it is not granted all the permissions by default for superuser ? Or Am I missing something here ?

permissions

```
class MyPermission(BasePermission):


    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        qs = myqs
        if request.method in ['put', 'patch']:
            return qs.filter(change=True).exists()
        elif request.method == 'post':
            return qs.filter(create=True).exists()
        elif request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return qs.filter(view=True).exists()
        elif request.method == 'delete':
            return qs.filter(delete=True).exists()
        else:
            return False
```

views

```
class MyView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset =qs
    permission_classes = [MyPermission]
```

settings

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
],
```

I solved the issue with this but I think it should not be necessary for superuser.

```
permission_classes = [IsAdminUser | MyPermission]
```

But I didn't get that why it is not granted all the permissions by default for `superuser` ?
Or Am I missing something here ?

Comment: What if I **don't** want to give permission to something to the superuser? That is the logical reason here.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I want to give all the systems permissions to the superuser without using model permissions.  Is it possible? I don't want to specify `IsAdminUser` in every permission class.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your permission class to something like this:

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission
class MyPermission(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True
        qs = myqs
        if request.method in ['put', 'patch']:
            return qs.filter(change=True).exists()
        elif request.method == 'post':
            return qs.filter(create=True).exists()
        elif request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return qs.filter(view=True).exists()
        elif request.method == 'delete':
            return qs.filter(delete=True).exists()
        else:
            return False
```

The reason you have to do this is because DRF does not consider superuser unless you're using [DjangoModelPermissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions)

**EDIT**

Only thing I can think of is that you inherit all permission classes from a custom permission class that checks if user is admin. Then you don't have to check in every single one.

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

# You can put this class in a separate file like
# 'base_permission.py' and import it anywhere you need it.
class SuperUserAllowAllPermission:

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True
        return super().has_permission(request, view)

class MyPermission(SuperUserAllowAllPermission, BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        qs = myqs
        if request.method in ['put', 'patch']:
            return qs.filter(change=True).exists()
        elif request.method == 'post':
            return qs.filter(create=True).exists()
        elif request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return qs.filter(view=True).exists()
        elif request.method == 'delete':
            return qs.filter(delete=True).exists()
        else:
            return False

class MyOtherPermission(SuperUserAllowAllPermission, BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'get':
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: I want to give all the systems permissions to the superuser without using model permissions. Is it possible? I don't want to specify IsAdminUser in every permission class.

Comment: I added a suggestion, maybe it's not what your looking for but it will provide some simplicity.